# Raphael JS detect canvas size when set as %

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using Raphael JS, and create a canvas with width set at `100%` of the container like so...

```
// there is a `div` with id `paper`
paper = Raphael('paper', '100%', '100%')
paper.circle(50, 40, 100)
```

Now I want to know how big the canvas is. how can I reliably find out the canvas size on all platforms?

I am not using jQuery.

---

**Update:** Potential workaround

Bonus points will be awarded for a solution that makes getting pixel width unnecessary, by making cavas scale proportionally. I am fairly sure this is possible with `canvas` so assume it is possible with Raphael, so that if I create all elements to a set width (say 100 pixel wide canvas) then I should be able to scale the canvas to `100%` of the screen, and the canvas should fill the screen, with all elements stretched appropriately, and keeping their proportions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the viewbox in order to scale to fit in full screen mode.

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setViewBox

You define a physical region (x, y, width, height) that contains your svg data, and everything will be scaled up while maintaining the proportions. The viewbox region is upscaled proportionally (when you specify false for fit) to the maximum size it can be inside the container.

```
paper.setViewBox(0, 0, 100, 100, false);​
```

Unfortunately, Raphael doesn't seem to give you the option of specifying how the overflow is handled. For example, you might wish to centre the view box so that any excess is spread evenly. If you have a 100 x 200 container and you have a 100 x 100 viewbox, then you have 100 pixels in height below the upscaled viewport, when you may wish for the viewport to have 50 pixels above and 50 pixels below.

In SVG these options are defined on the SVG container's `preserveAspectRatio` property. If you are not supporting the VML (lte ie8) option then you could change this property to affect the alignment.

http://premsobel.info/notes/ml/svg/viewports.html

As for detecting width and height in general, you are better off detecting the width or height of the parent node using `element.clientWidth` and `element.clientHeight`. I tend to avoid using body as the parent node and add my own inner container for detecting the size. Your canvas is 100% width/height of some container, so I would go looking for that container to find out what size it is.